# How to improve text rendering performance on. Custom text view on Gdk::Drawable

Tags: c++, performance, cairo, gtkmm, text-rendering

I'm trying to write a hex-editor-like thingie using Gtkmm and Gdk::Drawable. Just a hex-view to be precise.

At first I tried using Cairo which was awful. I guess I shouldn't get near anywhere Pango either.

Right now I'm using something like this: Using prerendered characters for text.

```
void HexView::on_vScrl_value_changed() {
    drawingArea.queue_draw();
}

bool HexView::DrawingArea::on_expose_event(GdkEventExpose* event) {
    /* */
    Glib::RefPtr<Gdk::Window> window = get_window();
    if(window && data && numBytes) {
        /* */
        unsigned int scrlY = hexView->vScrl.get_value();
        /* */

        for(/*loop visible bytes*/) {
            /* */
            window->draw_pixbuf(char_pixbuf, 0, 0, x, y, 20, 20, Gdk::RGB_DITHER_NONE, 0, 0);
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

This makes the rendering and scrolling bearable, but still slow. CPU hogged and scroll handle on a small spring, lagging behind a little. On a small 800x300 area :(

Any ideas to improve?

Gtk::TexView widget renders huge amounts of text perfectly and scrolling is nice on a 1600x1200 window.

Comment: Are you limiting your drawing to the visible area, or even better the dirty region?

Comment: Yes, everything is nice. Meanwhile I have figured that I can't squeeze anything faster out of Cairo or Pixbuf copying and the reason behind TextView's fast rendering was Pango which I initially avoided. So now I'm rendering hex dumps in paragraphs of text. How nice.

Comment: Also queue_draw() invalidates the whole area, might be able to do better with queue_draw_area(), depending on what you are doing there.

Comment: Thanks. My main goal was to get reasonable results while rendering the whole area. With huge scroll deltas, where the whole area would be invalidated anyway.